# Access NSMutableArray created in viewDidLoad on button tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

In my app I have an animation that plays when the user taps a button. In the IBAction method for the button tap, I am having it create a NSMutable Array, load the images into the array, then cycle through the images.

This results in a fair amount of lag between the button tap and the animation playing, but every tap after that is fine since the array is already created with the images.

I have tried placing the array creation and image loading in the vieDidLoad method, but for some reason the IBAction method (where the call to cycle through the images is) cannot access the array. How would I make the array available to it?

```
- (IBAction)tap {

NSMutableArray *anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage      imageNamed:@"0001.png"], ...(x30)... nil];

type.animationImages  = anim;
    type.animationDuration = 1.0;
    type.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [type startAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `NSMutableArray *anim` into your `UIViewController` `.h` file. It will make it available to global to access anywhere into your `.m` file.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0001.png"], ...(x30)... nil];
}

- (IBAction)tap 
{

    type.animationImages  = anim;
    type.animationDuration = 1.0;
    type.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [type startAnimating];

}
```

Comment: I placed the creation and loading of the mutable array in the vieDidLoad method, but the delay is still there. I don't think the array is being created when the view loads. `code` - (IBAction)tap:(id)sender {
    
    type.animationImages  = anim;
    type.animationDuration = 1.0;
    type.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [type startAnimating]; }  `code`  In the viewDidLoad: `code` {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0001.png"], etc, nil]; `code`

Comment: @DaleTownsend, `ViewDidLoad` would always call first. Then only your `IBAction` should call.

Comment: I know, I assumed that putting the creation and loading of the array in viewDidLoad would make it load the array so that when the button to play the animation (using the image array) was tapped, the animation would play without a delay. Is there any way I could preload the array so that there is no delay when tapping the button?

Answer (score 0):

Define NSMutableArray *anim in .h file ie class member variable

in viewDidLoad method defin like this:

```
anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage      imageNamed:@"0001.png"], ...(x30)... nil];
```

Use like this in button event:

```
 - (IBAction)tap 
{
  type.animationImages  = anim;
  type.animationDuration = 1.0;
  type.animationRepeatCount = 1;
  [type startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I placed the creation and loading of the mutable array in the vieDidLoad method, but the delay is still there. I don't think the array is being created when the view loads. `code` - (IBAction)tap:(id)sender { type.animationImages = anim; type.animationDuration = 1.0; type.animationRepeatCount = 1; [type startAnimating]; } `code` In the viewDidLoad: `code` { [super viewDidLoad]; anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0001.png"], etc, nil]; `code`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code may be it help full for you.
Array allocate one time when you tap first time.

```
if(!anim)
{
NSMutableArray *anim = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage      imageNamed:@"0001.png"], ...(x30)... nil];

   NSLog(@"array allocate");
}else
    {
       NSLog(@"array already allocated");
     }
```